# Crosswork error on intel xdk

Tags: android, cordova, intel-xdk, crosswalk

I am using Intel XDK for the first time and I can test the app in amulator.

I want to test working of sqlite plugin which cannot be done on the emulator. Unfortunately I can't seem to get my app installed on my device. I have installed the App preview as well. I am getting this error in the debug mode:

"Crosswalk version 18 is currently not supported in Project Preview for Applications."

I am able to test my phonegap app via eclipse on my mobile but not this one.

Comment: Same error here, a project that worked flawlessy 3 days ago now cannot be run anymore.

Comment: Change your CW version to 17 in the Build Settings. There is a problem with Debug modules (built by the Debug tab) and Crosswalk 18.

Comment: it works! Thanks! Maybe u you can add this as answer and i can correct it!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use productFlavor on the Grade file

```
 productFlavors {
        armv7 {
            versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode + 2
            ndk {
                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", ""
            }
        }
        x86 {
            versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode + 4
            ndk {
                abiFilters "x86", ""
            }
        }
    }
```

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html

Comment: thnx for the comment but can you please guide me as to where is the grade file? (I am making a hybrid app with intel xdk)

Comment: Unfortunately, the XDK build system does not allow for the use of extra gradle scripts in the project. Those that are built into the CLI project are not accessible, because they are not part of your project folder, they are added to the project in the cloud build server, which means you do not have the ability to modify them.